# Protect part of WordPress database from developer access

Tags: mysql, wordpress, security

I have a customer who wants his client's information to be protected such that even the website developer doesn't have access. Is this possible, and how would that have to be done?

I've been thinking of a MySQL database separate from the WP tables, with a separate password that only the customer controls.

Comment: In mysql you can grant user privileges which could in theory allow you to deny read access to specific tables on specific databases. Your developer won't like it though as it might make it very difficult for them to do their job.